# function not displaying objects in an array in API (but console.log works fine)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm in a pickle because my function is not displaying anything in an array.
I know there are 3 objects in an array (taken from an API):

PC
macOS
PlayStation

but when I try this code:

```
function platforms() {
    let platform = [];
    platform = details.platforms;

    for (let i = 0; i < platform.length; i++) {
        console.log(platform[i].platform.name);
        platform[i].platform.name;
    }
}
```

`console.log` works just fine but another line - `platform[i].platform.name;` - is showing me UNDEFINED.
Everything else works just fine. I can take titles, screenshots, score etc but not arrays unfortunately :(

And if it helps here is my slightly bigger piece of code:

```
function displayGameDetails(details) {

function platforms() {
    let platform = [];
    platform = details.platforms;

    for (let i = 0; i < platform.length; i++) {
        console.log(platform[i].platform.name);
        platform[i].platform.name;
    }
}

resultGrid.innerHTML = `
<div class="box">
    <p class="fourPara">${platforms()}</p>
</div >
`;
}
```

Comment: `console.log works just fine but another line - platform[i].platform.name; - is showing me UNDEFINED` given that line is doing literally nothing, I'm not sure how you're assessing that it's 'giving' you anything?

Comment: Why does each platform object have it's own nested property called "platform"?

Comment: What are you expecting the line `platform[i].platform.name;` to actually *do* and why?  Did you mean to *return* that value?  Or *aggregate* the values from that array and *return* that?

Comment: What does a minimal example of the API's JSON response look like?

Comment: @David There was no need to use RETURN before so maybe that's what I'm missing here. For example I just put ${details.name} and it displayed a game's title.I just want all objects from a platform array and display them all at once. I have 1 div where all the platforms would be, one under each other.

Comment: @Latrommi: If you want a function to return a value then there would indeed be a need to use `return`.  The line `platform[i].platform.name;` by itself does exactly nothing.

Comment: @David ok, so the only thing I've changed now, I've added RETURN so it's return platform[i].platform.name; but it's only showing me the first platform - PC

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan whenever I want something from an API, let's say a RATING I just use ${details.rating} and it's showing me that rating so I just assumed it'd work the same way with platforms, so platform[i].platform.name would show me each object (platform in this case) from an array of different types of platforms (PC, MAC etc). You can see I'm not that great in coding so maybe my logic is flawed.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl .platform.name is taken from an API (RAWG) so it's default if I understood you correctly.

Comment: It's showing only the first, because you are returning only the first one. You need to aggregate by mapping (and joining) or reducing the data as seen in my example below.

Comment: @Latrommi: Because that's what `return` does, it *returns* a value from the function.  Are you instead trying to *aggregate* the values from that array and return *that*?  You need to decide what you want that function to return.  Returning `platform[i].platform.name` will return exactly that... The *name* from the *platform* at position *i* in the *platform* array.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I appreciate your help and will take a look at your example then, thank you!

Comment: @David thanks David for your help, I appreciate it! Yes, I guess I need to aggregate them using map method but I'm still trying to figure out how to do this (I've never done this as you can see). I'll take a look at Mr.Polywhirl's example and will change some things in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify this greatly:

```js
const resultGrid = document.querySelector('.results-grid');

function displayPlatforms(platforms) {
  return platforms.map(({ name }) => {
    console.log(name);
    return `<span data-platform="${name}">${name}</span>`;
  }).join(', ')
}

function displayGameDetails(details) {
  resultGrid.innerHTML = `
    <div class="box">
        <p class="fourPara">
          Rating: ${details.rating}
        </p>
        <p class="fourPara">
          ${displayPlatforms(details.platforms)}
        </p>
    </div >
  `;
}

displayGameDetails({
  rating: 'mature',
  platforms: [
    { name: 'Windows' },
    { name: 'macOS' },
    { name: 'PlayStation' }
  ]
});
```

```css
[data-platform="Windows"]     { color: teal; }
[data-platform="macOS"]       { color: magenta; }
[data-platform="PlayStation"] { color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="results-grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works! Big thanks to Mr. Polywhirl and David.
Like David said I had to use RETURN keyword and Mr.Polywhirl pointed me in the right direction, the map() method!

(noob)SOLUTION

```
function displayGameDetails(details) {

const platformArray = details.platforms;
const platformAll = platformArray.map(function (singlePlatform) {
    return singlePlatform.platform.name;
})

resultGrid.innerHTML = `
<div class="box">
<p class="fourPara">${platformAll.join("<br/>")}</p>
</div>
`;
}
```